# How to have a background task on Outlook 365 Addin

Tags: office365, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins, outlook-restapi

I have previously developped an Outlook Addin based to VSTO and COM object.

This Addin do a specific check on each received email, and another one every 20sec with a System.Threading.Timer

I need to redev this Addin to be supported by O365 Outlook clients and Office 2016, by using Javascript.

Onto the Microsoft API, it seems not possible to do a "periodic action", in my exemple a webrequest to get a specific information every 20sec, and not possible to perform an action at each email received.

From what I understand, the addin must be "loaded" to perform an action, and to be loaded the user must click to a specific button (related to this plugin).

Are there any other method to perform my need ?

Answer (score 1):

Currently this feature (triggering a web add-in periodically / on mail receive, without user action), is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins). Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.